React rendering issue- object as props and props getting manipulated using deepclone
I have a React component <Grid /> which renders <SubGrid />
Now <grid /> is receiving props data and config.
My Grid Component is has a useEffect-
useEffect(() => {
        prepareAdaptableOptions();
    }, [data, config]);

this useEffect  has some code to deepclone data and config and then pass it down to <SubGrid />
Now my issue is - whenever <Grid /> is rendererd my subgrid updates on DOM ie., DOM is manipulated. even tho data and config that I passed are same.
And If I remove data, config from array of dependency then this useEffect does not even trigger when data and config is changed?
How do I resolve this issue ?

Please provide more code to explain your question.
